# How to debug Mac OS X pkg?

Tags: macos

I built a Mac OS X bundle `Frequon Invaders.app`, and it runs fine.  The executable was created with Go.  Then I packaged it like this:

```
$ pkgbuild --component 'Frequon Invaders.app' --install-location /Applications FrequonInvaders.pkg
pkgbuild: Adding component at /Users/Dad/Documents/projects/Frequon-Invaders-2.2/installer-macos/Frequon Invaders.app
pkgbuild: Wrote package to FrequonInvaders.pkg
```

When I open `FrequonInvaders.pkg` in Finder, I get a "install Frequon Invaders" window that lets me go through the motions of installing it, and the Summary part says "Installation was successful".  But when I look in `/Applications`, it's not there.  Indeed *none* of the files in the bundle were installed.

[Updated] After looking around, I found that the package appears to have been installed right on top of the original place that `Frequon Invaders.app` was originally built.  It seems that the `--install-location /Applications` was completely ignored!

Question:

- How do I use `pkgbuild` to build a package that is *really* installed where `install-location` said to install it?

Comment: Since writing the question, I've noticed that much software ships as a .dmg and not as a .pkg.  E.g., Skype, Open Office, H&R Block's tax software, GIMP, Flight Gear.  Evidently, Apple "packages" are not worth the frustration for many developers?

Comment: Apple packages are used a lot, by a lot of vendors, but they're usually for times when a `.dmg` doesn't fit (such as modifying system files).

Answer (score 3):

> How to debug Mac OS X pkg?

Debugging `.pkg` files is tricky because there's no easy way to get verbose output.

```
sudo installer -pkg my_package.pkg  -target / -verbose
```

This may help understand the step that's failing but it really doesn't help narrow the problem down...

Next, you can use a utility like **The Unarchiver** to extract the `.pkg` file.  Your scripts will need to be extracted twice by this utility.

**Note:** If you prefer the command line:

```sh
xar -xf my_package.pkg # extract pkg
tar -xf Scripts        # extract scripts
```

From there, you can attempt to troubleshoot what's going wrong with the scripts.

But in my case, the only way I was able to debug the scripts were to run the package over and over echoing debug statements to a file.

For example:

```sh
# preinstall
echo "here!" >> /Users/Tom/Desktop/debug.txt
```

Comment: When I run `xar -xf my_package.pkg` I don't get a `Scripts` folder but when I run pkgbuild it logs `Adding top-level postinstall script`. Any advice?

Comment: Apologies, my answer assumes `pkgbuild` was used.  If using `productbuild`, I believe the layout is different.  If you can share the `.pkg`, I'd be happy to take a look and modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for such simple installers it is always better to use a tool to do the work for you. I usually use the Packages tool

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

which is free and really really good.